# PHP foreach if isset

Tags: php, html, forms

I have 3 rows in database. When I click the button, it should send the selected data to session. However, the last row is always sent to the session. I want the data that I choose to be sent to the session (example: I choose the first row to send to the session)

```
<?php
            foreach ($search_row as $row){
                if(isset($_POST["aboutcafe"])){
                    $_SESSION["nama_cafe"] = $row["nama_cafe"];
                    header("Location: info_cafe.php");
                } 
            ?>
                <h4 class="text-white"><?= $row['nama_cafe'] ?></h4>
                <p class="text-justify"><?= $row['lokasi_cafe'] ?></p>
                <p class="letter">No Tel : <?= $row['notel_cafe'] ?></p>
                <br>
                <form method="post">
                    <button name="aboutcafe" class="btn btn-light">See about cafe</button>
                </form>

            <?php
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: You are looping through ALL the rows and aboutcafe is always set if clicked. So you will ALWAYS end up with the last row in the session. You probably need to look for a PHP (or any language) coding/logic tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need either a form, or a link, which, when submitted / clicked, will pass the ID of the cafe as a parameter (either through a hidden field, or a querystring parameter). That's basically how most web applications work when moving between different pieces of data.

To extend what you've already got, it could be something like

```
<form method="post" action="info_cafe.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="cafe" value="<?php echo $row["cafe_id"]; ?>"/>
  <button type="submit" name="aboutcafe" class="btn btn-light">See about cafe</button>
</form>
```

(and get rid of the `if(isset` bit).

Then when you submit the form to `cafe_info.php`, `$_POST["cafe_id"]` would have the relevant info.

Or you could replace the form with a hyperlink, e.g.

```
<a href="cafe_info.php?cafe_id=<?php echo $row["cafe_id"]; ?>">See about cafe</a>
```

And when that's clicked, it makes a GET (not a POST), and so in `cafe_info.php`, the `$_GET["cafe_id"]` parameter would contain the ID you need.

N.B. If it's not clear, using it this way means you don't need to involve the Session, which generally isn't a good design choice for this kind of task.